# How to pass dropdown selected value from view to controller through action link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting the id but I want the selected drop down value to be passed from view to controller.
I have action link,in that i need to pass

```
          @for(int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
            {
                <tr> 

                    <td>@Model[i].asset</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("state", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                       new SelectListItem {Value="--selec--"},
                       new SelectListItem {Text="Active",Value="Active"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text="Inactive",Value="Inactive"}
                        }
                        )



                              <span><a href="@Url.Action("Confirm",new { id = Model[i].id})"><input type="button" value ="Activate" class="btn btn-danger"/></a></span>






            }
```

Comment: Refer this link : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Pass-Send-DropDownList-Selected-Value-to-Controller-using-HtmlActionLink.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for passing the view to the controller make function:

```
 public MapperFunction()
    {
        CreateMap<modelname, Databasetablename>();

    }
    public static void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<MapperFunction>();
        });
    }
```

and its values used in the model and this are used to pass the data from view to contoller

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a form on the page (view)? If you have a form then make the form method 'Post'.
This will post back the selected value in the drop down list.

Otherwise you can write a javascript and bind it to the click event of the button.
Then on click get the selected value, add to the action Url and then navigate. [ Not recommended option ].